# Get first value from List of ViewBag in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to get first value of column article_name from ViewBag.articlelist.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.articlelist = (from a in dbcontext.cms_article select a ).ToList();
```

**View**

I just try to do like this .

```
ViewBag.articlelist['article_name'][0];
```

Thank You!

Comment: I not recommand getting first value after `ToList`,it'll get all table data to memory first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewBag` is of type `dynamic` so you should be able to get the value like this:

```
var articleName = ViewBag.articlelist?[0]?.article_name;
```

where I'm using the null-propagation operator (`?[]` and `?.`) to handle null values.

If you're iterating over the collection you will need to cast it to a list:

```
@foreach (var article in (List<cms_article>)ViewBag.articlelist)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You!. This exactly what im looking for =D